# Custom labeling expression in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

I'm trying to use an expression to label a layer by using the "name" field but only if it has certain entries from the "type" field. The expression I've tried is:

```
NAME IF  "TYPE" IN  ('RIV-MAJ', 'LAKE-PER')
```

Can someone suggest how I would go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to assign the values which is stored in the `"NAME"` field when the value stored in the `"TYPE"` field is `'RIV-MAJ'` or `'LAKE-PER'`, you may use this expression:

```py
CASE
WHEN "TYPE"='RIV-MAJ' OR "TYPE"='LAKE-PER'
THEN "NAME"
END
```